# Which package contains rhn_register?

Tags: yum, rhn, spacewalk

Spacewalk has been installed, runs and can be accessed. The expectation was that installing Spacewalk was sufficient in order to run **rhn_register**.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rhn_register
sudo: rhn_register: command not found
```

The idea was that there would be a **rhn_register** package.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install rhn_register
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * epel: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
 * extras: mirror.netrouting.net
 * jpackage-generic: sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de
 * updates: mirror.netrouting.net
No package rhn_register available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Googling **install rhn_register** did not help to solve the issue.

Comment: `yum whatprovides */rhn_register`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from CentOS 7. Exact results may be different if you are using RHEL, other versions of CentOS, Scientific Linux, etc. :

`yum whatprovides */rhn_register`

`rhn-setup-2.0.2-5.el7.noarch : Configure and register an RHN/Spacewalk client`

Here is a brief YUM tutorial, courtesy of RedHat => [What is yum and how to use it?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9934)

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. Installing this package results in some dependency issues. Running `yum whatprovides */rhn_register` is helpful. Perhaps you could add this to the answer as well. I will try some other packages and let you know the outcome.

Comment: There were some dependency issues running various packages, but `sudo yum install -y rhn-setup-2.3.5-1.el7.noarch` works. Thank you (+1).